# How to save folder of images to iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image, uiimage

I have a folder in my computer which contains 223 png files, representing country flags. Which would be the most recommended way to store them inside an iOS app? I am thinking about dragging the folder to the app location inside xcodeproject but I have no idea on how to access it through code? Are there any recommendations, official way of how one should do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly drag the folder-full of images into your Xcode project. Then you would use methods in the Bundle class to load those images.

There are advantages to using an asset catalog to hold your images however. I would suggest dragging the contents of your images folder into your app's asset catalog and letting Xcode manage the images for you.